# Asterisk help on understanding about texting

Tags: voip, asterisk, sms-gateway, voicemail

Hi i am new to Asterisk , I installed Asterisk in my ubuntu , i want to know what is next , I want to sent sms , and voice mail , i am a developer please advice me, How and what to do next

Answer (score 1):

Now you have start read books

I recomend order ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony" and read it first.

After that you need install elastix or trixbox and see how it designed, check common practice etc.

For more info you can check voip-info.org project and asterisk.org